# Rails: Sorting Associated Records Dynamically

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

Tried looking for a way to sort associated records from parent model, but only came up with static ways by hardcoding the sort in the model file itself. Like this example: [Rails sorting associated records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521362/rails-sorting-associated-records)
But I want to sort 'on the fly' using a table like this RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables. 
The table works and sorts beautifully if I have the info sitting on the parent model obviously, but I don't want my model's DB table being too wide, so I want to pull from the associated model Example:

```
Product.order("#{sort_column_p} #{sort_direction}").page(page).per_page(per_page)

def sort_column_p
  columns = %w[sku orders.qty]
  columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
end
def sort_direction
  params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
end
```

When I try and sort this way I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'orders.qty' in
'order clause': SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products`  WHERE `products`.`user_id` = 
1 ORDER BY orders.qty asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0)
```

The associated Models being:

Parent: Product
Child: Order

Thanks for your help guys and girls!
Edit: Btw, yes the models have the appropriate has_many & belongs_to parameters in the correct models with the foreign key in the child being correctly lined up with the parent model.

Edit 2: So after a bunch of debugging this is how it will look in SQL:

```
SELECT Products.sku, Orders.qty
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Products.id=Orders.product_id
```

So now its just a matter of getting it into Rails format! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it completely, but have you tried `Product.includes(:orders).order(...`.  The error is saying you're missing to include `orders` table in your query.

Comment: I appreciate your enthousiasm on sorting etc., but have you looked at Ransack to sort and search your tables? This allows everything you're currently implementing by hand...  https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: DannyVanHoof I'm not trying add yet another gem onto my already huge gemset for my big project. Thanks for the idea though.
@vee your answer wasn't the right one, but it def led me to the correct answer.. SQL wise. I still need to change it to Rails code. I edited the answer to include the SQL way of doing it. I'm sure I can easily figure it out, but if you want to convert it to Rails Syntax and put it as an answer, I'll up vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need the `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, you need to specify most of the SQL yourself, even with Rails, to wit:

```
Product.joins('left join orders on products.id=orders.product_id').select('products.sku, orders.qty')
```

If you could get by with an `INNER JOIN`, then this would simplify to:

```
Product.joins(:tables).select('products.sku, orders.qty')
```

Comment: Yup this is exactly what I ended up using. Thanks for the help everyone, still getting used to SQL statements :)